# C#: String Variable Not Passing Value to Parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parameters

This is probably a simple fix, however I've spent a few hours trying to get this code to work.  For my homework assignment, I have to open a text file and place it's data in an ArrayList.  I did just that, but then I realized that I am required to do so but creating a method called ReadFileAndStoreInArrayList.  Now here is where I am having trouble.

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            *//This string variable "file" is saying it has been
            //assigned but never used.*
            string file = @"C:\Users\Latoy\Documents\Schoolwork\IT 232\Unit 5\FamousWords.txt";

        }
        *//Here is where I attempted to pass the variable by value*.
        public void ReadFileAndStoreInArrayList(string file)
        {
            ArrayList FamousWords = new ArrayList();

            using (StreamReader path = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = path.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    FamousWords.Add(line);
                }
            }
            foreach (string line in FamousWords)
            {
                Console.Write(line);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

I am fairly new to this, and I have done my research and still can not find what I am doing wrong. Is it the way I called the method? *Note: The code works when placed in one method, however I am required to create a method.  I attempted to use just the ReadFileAndStoreInArrayList method but the compiler is making me use the main method as well.*

Comment: Not to throw something unrelated in, but it concerns me a little if someone is teaching a class and even using `ArrayList`. I don't think anyone uses it ever, because it's a collection with no type. You only see that in code from around 2005 or before.

Comment: Yeah as I worked with ArrayLists I noticed that list<> is a better choice.  Sadly, I have 30 grand invested in this schooling and I have no choice but to finish.  In addition to my intermediate software development class, I am taking a Desktop Administration class for God knows what reason and it's centered around Windows 8.1.  I have 8 months.  I'm not going back for my bachelors.. Instead I will get a MCSD study guide and learn off that.  My advice? Don't go to a for profit school.

Comment: If programming is your thing then a little bad information won't hurt anyway. Everyone knows what they're talking about, but many of them are very, very wrong, even when you get into the workplace. Half the challenge is figuring out who to listen to. If your instructor is giving you questionable information and you've figured out where he/she is off then you're on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Use `static` keyword for the method you want to call from your main function, or else you won't be able to call it.

```
    public static void ReadFileAndStoreInArrayList(string file)
    {
        ArrayList FamousWords = new ArrayList();

        using (StreamReader path = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = path.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                FamousWords.Add(line);
            }
        }
        foreach (string line in FamousWords)
        {
            Console.Write(line);
        }
    }
```

And then you can call it just like:

```
ReadFileAndStoreInArrayList(file);
```

in your main function which should look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            *//This string variable "file" is saying it has been
            //assigned but never used.*
            string file = @"C:\Users\Latoy\Documents\Schoolwork\IT 232\Unit 5\FamousWords.txt";
            ReadFileAndStoreInArrayList(file);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually calling your method anywhere.  You're missing a call to:

```
ReadFileAndStoreInArrayList(file);
```